# SqlConnection in aspx

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, localdb

I am not to aspx. I have had issues connecting to the database, I keep getting the error message

> Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

The error is line 20 but I don't see the error. Please I need help.

Line 20:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="c:\Users\truparse creative\documents\visual studio 2013\WebSites\ams\App_Data\asm.mdf"; Integrated Security=True");
```

Answer (score 3):

ASP assumes that you are closing a statement with another double quotation. Remove the double quotation from `"c:\Users\truparse creative\documents\visual studio 2013\WebSites\ams\App_Data\asm.mdf"`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this;

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="c:\\Users\\truparse creative\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\WebSites\\ams\\App_Data\\asm.mdf"; Integrated Security=True;");
```

Comment: With `@"` you don't need to escape \, but you do need to escape `"`. Cyval's answer is correct, the double quotes are not actually needed, but if they were, they'd need to be escaped by using `""`.